# How trigger an action by setting a time in android app using cordova?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The user should able to set a date and time in future and when the time has come the app should automatically call a function x(). Is there any CORDOVA pulgin to do this and how can I use it?

Thanks,
Amir

Answer (score 0):

You dont need cordova to achieve that, you can do in JS with something like this:

```
function delayFunction (delay) {

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        yourFunction();
    }, delay);

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Del, But if I close my app how this function will get Triggered?

Comment: If the app is in background. the function will be triggered. If its closed, it wont. What you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry if my description was not clear. By time I did'nt meant a time period, I meant I have to set a specific date and time, and have to trigger an action at that specific time even if the app is closed.